# How to get numbers after special character using regex

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re
string = "He go $200 and umm go $136.33. His ssn number:987-645-33 and the got credit:973647 with 155 percent discount "
a = re.findall(r"(?:(?<=ssn number:)|(?<=credit:)|(?<=$))[\w\d-]+",string)
print(a)

Required solution:['$200','$136.33','987-645-33','973647']
```

Is there any solution to get the $ values using the regex. The $ symbol should be added in list

Comment: Your lookbehind is wrong.  It should be `(?<=\$)` ... the dollar sign needs to be escaped.

Comment: I need the $ added to list. Required output: $200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version which also captures dollar amounts:

```py
import re
string = "He go $200 and umm go $136.33. His ssn number:987-645-33 and the got credit:973647 with 155 percent discount "
a = re.findall(r"(?:(?<=ssn number:)|(?<=credit:)|\$)\d+(?:[.-]\d+)*", string)
print(a)  # ['$200', '$136.33', '987-645-33', '973647']
```